# View wants to know that i am partial view or view ?

Tags: .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

View wants to know that i am partial view at the moment or not.

I know that i can send data from controller to view which hold partial or view value but there can be something built in in view side which i can detect view type itself.

Comment: eh... what? I don't understand your question. Try rephrasing it.

Comment: Inside a view, i want to know that this view is called as partial or as normal view.

Comment: A view typically represents a full HTML page, with head, body, etc whereas a partial view is usually just a piece of the body so it seems kind of weird that you're calling the same view partially and non-partially.

Comment: @Julien Lebosquain - Think about login form. You can show it as widget(partial) on your main page and also you can show it as view in body. What is weird about that ?? The view can be partial and view, it is matter where do you use them .

Comment: So your view has custom logic to include or exclude the master page / layout file or head tags depending on whether it's partial or not? Then just make it partial and include it in a full view.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK there is no way to achieve this without passing this information to the partial either as part of the view model or as part of the ViewData when rendering this partial.

I can't foresee a situation where something like this could be useful. The only purpose that a view should have is to display the data which is passed under the form of a view model. And of course based on properties of this view model decide to include or not different sections.

Comment: Rendering code being depended of view type(partial or view) is design smell ?

Answer (score 0):

If you used child actions instead, you could inspect:

```
this.ViewContext.IsChildAction
```